# Update from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I'm a new user to Linux, but I'm coming along well.  I currently have Ubuntu 17.10 installed on my laptop ssd with the home folder on the hdd.  When it comes time to upgrade to 18.04, will I be able to run the auto update or will I need to follow a different process?

Comment: Have you ever update Ubuntu before?

Comment: No, only a fresh install.  I've looked over info online on doing the upgrade, but it doesn't mention anything about modified installs

Comment: See this article https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-ubuntu-version/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ubuntu update manager will show you a few days after the release an additional button for distribution upgrade next to the packages which can be upgraded. The distribution update will not be installed automatically even if you setup the system to install updates automatically.

The update should not change configs regarding how you mounted the SSD and HDD but just install a lot of updated packages.

Answer (score 0):

The version upgrade is basically just a more thorough version of what you see with `apt-get upgrade`.  It will not touch your home directory at all.

Comment: Are you saying that I just follow the upgrade process as seen https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver, or do I download an update version to install?

Comment: Your link is a 404 but you'd better check out the official Ubuntu documentation anyway.  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Sorry about that tripleee.  It didn't like the quotes.  Here is the link.  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver

Comment: Yeah, the command-line process is absolutely superior if you are comfortable with that. Either way, make sure you have backups before you plunge ahead - especially before the official release, you should be aware that there is a risk involved.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a fairly new install for me, so the risk isn't huge.  I have my home directory backed up, so I should be good.  I actually did a normal system install that gave me an LVM structure about 3 weeks ago, then I came across recommendations from a few sources that suggested creating my own drive format with Boot, root and home.  This made sense to me and it allowed me to use my hdd for my home.  Thanks again for your input.

Comment: I would NOT recommend using apt-get for distribution upgrades on ubuntu. They have a ``do-release-upgrade`` utility which is like the update manager for the shell. The difference is, that their update-programs do more stuff to prepare the system for the new release than just upgrading packages. And then probably using the GUI tools is the best choice for novice users.

Comment: The Linux Config guide mentions that too, although it's not their first alternative.